# CSS is not being applied after changes

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-3

I have problem where I can't apply the style in CSS in my ASP.NET MVC application. 
The behavior is it applies for the first time and then the subsequent changes to the CSS is not getting reflected in my _Layout.cshtml. I am not sure what I am missing here.

### CSS file

```
body
{
    font-size: .85em;
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
    color: #232323;
    background-color: #fff;
}

header,
footer,
nav,
section {
    display: block;
}

/* Styles for basic forms
-----------------------------------------------------------*/

fieldset 
{
    border:1px solid #ddd;
    padding:0 1.4em 1.4em 1.4em;
    margin:0 0 1.5em 0;
}

legend 
{
    font-size:1.2em;
    font-weight: bold;
}

textarea 
{
    min-height: 75px;
}

.editor-label 
{
    margin: 1em 0 0 0;
}

.editor-field 
{
    margin:0.5em 0 0 0;
}


/* Styles for validation helpers
-----------------------------------------------------------*/
.field-validation-error
{
    color: #ff0000;
}

.field-validation-valid
{
    display: none;
}

.input-validation-error
{
    border: 1px solid #ff0000;
    background-color: #ffeeee;
}

.validation-summary-errors
{
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #ff0000;
}

.validation-summary-valid
{
    display: none;
}
#Header
{
    color:white;
    padding:1px;
}
#Content
{
    float:left;
    margin:10px;
}
#SideBar
{
    float :left;
    margin:10px;
    padding :10px;
    border:  dotted 1px  red;
    width:180px;
    font-style:italic;
}
#Footer
{
    text-align:center;
    clear:both;
}
```

For example I changed "border" in #SideBar from red to black. But it always show red. I might be doing something fundamentally wrong here.

### _Layout.cshtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
       <!--link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />-->
      <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/SiteStyle.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/modernizr-1.7.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
   <div id="Header" style="background-image: url('/Content/Images/Banner_Final3.png'); background-repeat:no-repeat; width :1500px; height : 150px;"   >

   </div>
   <div id="SideBar">
       @Html.Partial("UserControls/UserLogin", new AlanBeezLab.Models.LoginModel())
   </div>
   <div id="Content">
        @RenderBody()
   </div>
   <div id="Footer">
        <p>Copyright &copy; XXXXXXX</p>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

However, if rename the physical file and change the reference in _Layout.cshtml, I could see the changes I made.

Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 109, accepted):

Hit the Ctrl-F5 for reloading the page without using the cached contents

Comment: Useful links :http://www.stefanhayden.com/blog/2006/04/03/css-caching-hack/   http://css-tricks.com/can-we-prevent-css-caching/

Comment: <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/SiteStyle.css?@new System.Random().NextDouble().ToString()")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />   -- This works as well. I added a random number at the end as above

Answer (score 14):

The browser can cache static files such as CSS files.

If you update a CSS file and the change does not appear when you browse, try using CTRL-F5 within your browser.

Comment: +1 that's usually it :). Another tip if you're testing in IE: hit F12 to activate the developer toolbar and in the "Cache" menu there's an option "Always refresh from server". Can be useful while developing styles.

Answer (score 3):

This will work when anything else won't, like in my case:

Credit goes to: `atticae`

You can append a random query parameter to the stylesheet url (for example via javascript or server side code). It will not change the css file that is being loaded, but it will prevent caching, because the browser detects a different url and will not load the cached stylesheet.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://mysite/style.css?id=1234">
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately ctrl+f5 does not work for me. I have to go to Chrome: F12 -> Network tab -> right click within white area where all the get and post records are -> Clear browser cache. Now if you press ctrl + f5 or just f5 it should work.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was I had a resource style file which was referring by the code

```
string location = Page.ClientScript.GetWebResourceUrl(typeof(PageBase), "MyNS.Common.Web.Base.CommonStyle.css");
LiteralControl include = new LiteralControl(string.Format(tempLink, location));
```

When I change / add some style in the file it was not reflecting in the **CommonStyle.css**
it was not reflecting in the web page even after clearing the cache(ctrl + f5 , ctrl + shift + f5)?

On my analysis I found the reason was -

> stop the debugging, rebuild the solution and run it again so that all
>   the web resource styles load once again, simply clearing the cache as
>   we does normally for any html change will not help,after doing this my 
>   change in the style got reflected in the web page and it fixed my problem.