# CSS sheet not affecting the layout

Tags: html, css, visual-studio, razor

first of all, I couldn't find a way to phrase my problem in one sentence, so I'll try to be more explicit in the post.
So I've been developing on VS, essentially doing web development with Razor MVC, for almost a year now and there's something that has been bugging me. On most of my projects I use a unique stylesheet in which I put all of my rules. My problem is, if I reload the page, the CSS won't apply and I have to make a change to my CSS and save it for the rest of the sheet to works. I also noticed that if I leave VS, the CSS now apply permanently. So it's not really a big issue that won't let me work properly, but still it's a bit boring to have to change a value and then hit ctrl+z each time I reload the page.

So I wanted to know if anyone had had the same problem, and if yes what was the solution; and if no, I'll listen to any idea.

Thanks for your time and have a nice day :)

Comment: Are your sure it's not the cache? This might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6303053/css-is-not-being-applied-after-changes

Comment: nop, even with f5 I still have to change something then put it back to normal afterward for my css to applies