# Broken ASP.NET UI

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am developing an ASP.NET MVC 5 application for a while now.

After an update that changed a lot the database structure, the UI has gone crazy. I think this is a IIS issue since it is only on the client's machine and I am not able to replicate it, but I don't know where to start looking for it.

I have tried to restart everything, but with no resolve.

This is going on for days and I am out of ideas.
[image]

As it can be seen in the picture, the CSS is not working correctly, the pictures are not showing and the Resource data (for switching the language) is crazy.

I don't know if the update did something or not, but it shouldn't since I changed the models and controllers only. I did delete some screens, but this shouldn't impact.

If I deploy it on a fresh machine there is no problem.

I know this question is really ambiguous, but I have looked into the cshtml files are I could't find errors and I do not know what info / code to give. I can update if someone can help.

Update:

Thank you for all your responses. Sorry for my late one. I didn't expect answers so fast. Here is how it looks on mine:
[image]

The bigger problem is that I do not have access to their server. I am working with somebody else on the phone and they send me pictures.

UPDATE 2:

It didn't work with CTRL+F5 and clearing browsing history (I didn't thought about this since it is the same on two laptops they are using to access the app). They are not allowed to install other browsers than Mozilla and Internet Explorer. They are using Mozilla by default. Opening the app in Internet Explorer improved the situation. The Resource works and the CSS is improved, but the pictures still aren't showing.

This is how it looks on IE:[image]

They use a laptop as a server and access the app on 2 other. It is a temporary solution until a server will be bought.

Comment: What does it look like on your other machine?

Comment: Also, does it show any errors in the browser console? Is this the same across all browsers?

Comment: What browser is the client using? Does it work for them in other browsers?

Comment: Did client try to delete **all** browser cache?

Comment: Also, try this maybe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6303053/css-is-not-being-applied-after-changes

Comment: Did you make any CSS or JavaScript changes? Browser caching can really trip you up in these cases.

Comment: Also possibly relevant: https://superuser.com/questions/1195404/force-google-chrome-to-check-for-new-javascript-files-every-time-i-access-a-web

Comment: press "ctrl+f5" or open it in "incognito"

Comment: Can you clarify whether any of the suggestions so far have helped?

Comment: I am waiting for the response. Sorry for my late one. I didn't expect so quick answer. Thank you very much to all you guys!

Comment: How is the application deployed?

Comment: Assuming you basically just give them a published copy of the project, you need to make sure that they delete everything from the previous version when copying the new version over.

Comment: The problem is solved with your solution @Tieson T. You can post it as an answer and I will mark it. I think it is the 50th time I send the update and until now, no problems appeared...

Comment: Thanks to all you guys for the fast answers!